# Linq to Entities Group Sum Calculated Property

Tags: c#-4.0, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5

Using C# 4 and EF5.

Having trouble with attempting to sum a calculated property:

```
The specified type member 'QtyAvailable' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.
```

Here is the property definition:

```
public decimal QtyAvailable
    {
        get
        { return this.QtyInContainer - this.QtyAllocated; }
    }
```

Here is the Linq:

```
var viewModel =
                companyItems
                        .GroupJoin(
                            inventory,
                            items => items.Id,
                            inven => inven.ItemId, (im, icd) => new { im, icd }
                            )
                        .SelectMany(
                            itemInven => itemInven.icd.DefaultIfEmpty(),
                            (im, icd) => new { im, icd }
                        )
                        .GroupBy(g => new
                            {
                                g.im.im.Id
                            }
                        )
                        .Select(group =>
                                new ItemAvailabilityViewModel()
                                {
                                    Id = group.Key.Id,
                                    QtyAvailable = group.Sum(jt => jt.icd == null ? 0 : jt.icd.QtyAvailable),
                                    UnitCashPrice = group.Max(jt => jt.im.im.UnitSellPrice),
                                    UnitCreditPrice = group.Max(jt => jt.im.im.UnitSellPrice * (1 + company.CashDiscountPct)),
                                    CustomerUnitPrice = group.Max(jt => jt.im.im.UnitSellPrice * (1 + decCreditPriceMarkup))
                                }
                        )
                        ;
```

Not sure how to acheive this result. Do I need to somehow break this into 2 queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like breaking this into 2 queries was the ticket. From what I guess is happening is that in the first, when you call .ToList(), it resolves the calculated property, making it in essence no longer calculated for the second query to then sum it. Here is the resulting code:

```
//join of Recpt Header and Detail
            var unGroupedJoin =
                companyItems
                        .GroupJoin(
                            inventory,
                            items => items.Id,
                            inven => inven.ItemId, (im, icd) => new { im, icd }
                            )
                        .SelectMany(
                            itemInven => itemInven.icd.DefaultIfEmpty(),
                            (im, icd) => new { im, icd }
                        ).ToList();

            var viewModel =
                unGroupedJoin
                        .GroupBy(g => new
                            {
                                g.im.im.Id
                            }
                        )
                        .Select(group =>
                                new ItemAvailabilityViewModel()
                                {
                                    Id = group.Key.Id,
                                    QtyAvailable = group.Sum(jt => jt.icd == null ? 0 : jt.icd.QtyAvailable),
                                    UnitCashPrice = group.Max(jt => jt.im.im.UnitSellPrice),
                                    UnitCreditPrice = group.Max(jt => jt.im.im.UnitSellPrice * (1 + company.CashDiscountPct)),
                                    CustomerUnitPrice = group.Max(jt => jt.im.im.UnitSellPrice * (1 + decCreditPriceMarkup))
                                }
                        ).ToList()
                        ;
```